# Linking to assets without assetic

Tags: symfony, twig, assets

I am having trouble understanding the following approaches of linking to assets. Note the following scenarios.

I was able to link to an asset as follows, using assetic:

```
  {% image '@VendorTestBundle/Resources/public/images/widb_logo.png' %}
        <img src="{{ asset_url }}" />
  {% endimage %}
```

However, I would like to access assets in the public directory freely (with or without assetic) and the following approach fails to link properly for some reason:

```
<img src="{{ asset('VendorTestBundle/Resources/public/images/sunset.png' }}" />
```

I appreciate any advice on how to fix this problem.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try `asset("/bundles/vendortestbundle/images/widb_logo.png")`? (After an assets:install of course).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your image in the web directory like

```
C:\wamp\www\yourpackage\web\bundles\yourbundle\images\sunset.png
```

Access it using

```
<img src="{{asset('bundles/yourbundle/images/sunset.png')}}" alt="" />
```

You have another way, but bad idea and highly discouraged

```
<img src="/yourpackage/web/bundles/yourbundle/images/sunset.png" alt="" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's frowned upon by the community, but I usually just stick a folder called images in the web/ directory, then in my twig templates, I just use the good old fashioned

```
<img src="/images/path/to/image" alt="whatever">`
```

I think it's helpful to remember that Symfony is designed to help out your development process and that you don't have to use every feature that ships with it. Personally, I think assetic is overkill in many situations, but I know that my opinion goes against the prevailing wisdom, so take it with a grain of salt.